# Should "more often than not" be between commas in a sentence?

Tags: expressions, commas

I'm writing an essay for college and I'm unsure if I should add commas in between "more often than not".

What I wrote: "However, a topic as important as sex education is, is, more often than not, a taboo amongst parents and families."

I was thinking maybe it should be like this: "However, a topic as important as sex education is, is more often than not a taboo amongst parents and families."

Comment: It's a matter of stylistic choice whether or not to separate out the phrase with commas - but why have you repeated _is_ in both examples?

Comment: It was a mistake, thanks for noticing it out. I wrote this really late last night, in my mind it made sense.